# how to unit test of this function using TDD ?

Tags: javascript, tdd, jestjs

I am new for unit test and TDD method so could you help me please.

```
function calculate(a, b) {
    var sum = a + b;
    var sub = a - b;
    return { sum: sum, sub: sub };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With jest you can do it like this :

```
describe('calculation', ()=> {
  let result
  beforEach(()=>{
    result = calculate(2, 3)
  })
  it('returns the correct sum', (){
    expect(result.sum).toBe(5)
  })
  it('returns the correct sub', (){
    expect(result.sub).toBe(-1)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Andreas Köberle . It works and I know the idea how to test unit function using jest.

Answer (score 1):

```
it('checks calculations', function() {  
    var calculate = require('./example.js');
    expect(calculate(1, -1).sum).toBe(0);
    expect(calculate(1, -1).sub).toBe(2); 
});
```

Save the file as a .js and use npm test.
I am assuming that you are using **jestjs**.
You can definitely add other test conditions depending upon your understanding of the function.

Comment: Thank you very much @Yash . It works and I know the idea how to test unit function using jest.

Answer (score 0):

A very different answer here: the huge problem with testing such code *manually* is the fact that it is hard to tell when you wrote *enough* tests covering different cases.

An alternative approach here: instead of specifying only expected results you step back and identify the **contracts** that your method under test should adhere to.

And then you use one of the quickcheck-based frameworks, such as [JSVerify](http://jsverify.github.io/). You give those *rules* to the tool - and then the tool creates random data and runs test cases. And it case it finds violations of the contract, it will then try to "minimize" the test input - so that you, in the end receive a message "when you use this data x,y,z then rule A is violated".

It is a very different approach compared to "normal" TDD and unit testing, but especially for such kind of functionality it can be a very effective additional thing to do.

Comment: You are very welcome. Obviously the answer by Andreas would be your first choice to accept ... but maybe you remember this answer - and come the day you reach 15 rep and upvote rights you come back and also upvote the helpful stuff you got.